# Multiple CassandraTemplates in Repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

I am building a SpringBoot App using Spring-Data-Cassandra (1.5.RC1) and Cassandra 3.x

Now, this is my CassandraConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:META-INF/cassandra.properties" })
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = { "com.rg" })
public class CassandraConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CassandraConfig.class);

@Bean
public CassandraClusterFactoryBean XCluster() {

    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
    cluster.setContactPoints(environment.getProperty("cassandra.X.contactpoints"));
    cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("cassandra.X.port")));
    return cluster;
}

@Bean
public CassandraMappingContext XMappingContext() {
    return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
}

@Bean
public CassandraConverter XConverter() {
    return new MappingCassandraConverter(XMappingContext());
}

@Bean
public CassandraSessionFactoryBean XSession() throws Exception {

    CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
    session.setCluster(XCluster().getObject());
    session.setKeyspaceName(environment.getProperty("cassandra.X.keyspace"));
    session.setConverter(XConverter());
    session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.NONE);
    return session;
}

@Bean
public CassandraOperations XCassandraTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new CassandraTemplate(XSession().getObject());
}

@Bean
public CassandraClusterFactoryBean orgCluster() {

    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
    cluster.setContactPoints(environment.getProperty("cassandra.org.contactpoints"));
    cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("cassandra.org.port")));
    return cluster;
}


@Bean
public CassandraMappingContext orgMappingContext() {
    return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
}

@Bean
public CassandraConverter orgConverter() {
    return new MappingCassandraConverter(activityMappingContext());
}

@Bean
public CassandraSessionFactoryBean orgSession() throws Exception {

    CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
    session.setCluster(activityCluster().getObject());
    session.setKeyspaceName(environment.getProperty("cassandra.org.keyspace"));
    session.setConverter(activityConverter());
    session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.NONE);
    return session;
}

@Bean
public CassandraOperations orgCassandraTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new CassandraTemplate(orgSession().getObject());
}
```

}

This is my Repository:

```
public interface ActivityRepository extends CassandraRepository<Activity> {

@Query("SELECT * FROM activities2 WHERE actor_id=?0")
Iterable<Activity> findByActor_Id(String actor_Id);

// @Query("SELECT * FROM activities2 WHERE viewer_id='?0'")
// Iterable<Activity> findByApp_Id(String appId);
```

}

However, the app fails to load with the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'XController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'XService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'XService' defined in file [/Users/jarvis/Documents/workspace/XStreamLog/bin/com/rg/Xstream/service/XService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'XRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cassandraTemplate' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:552)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.rg.Xstream.Application.main(Application.java:16)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'XService' defined in file [/Users/jarvis/Documents/workspace/XStreamLog/bin/com/rg/Xstream/service/XService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'XRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cassandraTemplate' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'XRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cassandraTemplate' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1492)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:552)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cassandraTemplate' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:685)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 45 more
```

I don't undersatnd how the cassandraTemplate in the previous version of the project was Autowired into the app without me explicitly stating so in the code. If I can understand that I can get rid of this error. Any leads ?

Comment: You need to provide at least one bean named `cassandraTemplate` when using `@EnableCassandraRepositories` default settings, or specify `@EnableCassandraRepositories(cassandraTemplateRef=…)`

Comment: You have not created the CassandraTemplate bean and hence its giving the error.  @Bean
    public CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new CassandraTemplate(session().getObject());
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code as example:

```
@Configuration
public class CassandraConfig {

    @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints(cassandraContactPoints);
        cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(cassandraPort));
        return cluster;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() {
        return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraConverter converter() {
        return new MappingCassandraConverter(mappingContext());
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws Exception {
        CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
        session.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
        session.setKeyspaceName(cassandraKeyspace);
        session.setConverter(converter());
        session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.NONE);
        return session;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new CassandraTemplate(session().getObject());
    }
}
```